# JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am now trying to use Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, but I have a difficult problem!

I've done the following Settings in JMeter .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoBg.png)

And I configured the proxy in firefox.

Then I recorded a simple script.

But when I replayed the script, it didn't work, and I got the following tips:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thq32.png)

What should I do? Please give me some advice!Thanks!

Comment: @StefanStoichev, jriginal question had 2 different images, be more carefull.

Comment: @Qwertiy i thought they are looking the same and ive quickly compared the date values but probably looked at the different sections in the same picture. Sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand two things:

1. Why you are asking Badboy-related question in JMeter forum?
2. How it can be convenient to use 2 separate tools while JMeter has its own [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)?

So please retry recording using [JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and if the issue persists - come back here so we could take a look into the issue.

---

There is one more alternative solution for JMeter tests recording which used to work under any conditions: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), you can consider it as a fallback solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice gave me great help. I am now trying to use JMeter's Proxy Server, but encountering a very thorny problem, can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

No one will ever read this or benefit from it, but just in case....

Right click your test plan and select Add > Listener > View Results Tree.
Re-run your script and read what's in the results tree.